# IndexError: list index out of range, but list length OK

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

New to programming, looking for a deeper understanding on whats happening.

Goal: open a file and print the first 10 lines. (similar to head command)

**Code:**

```
with open('file') as f: 
      for i in range(0,10): 
          print([line.strip('\n') for line in f][i])
```

**Result:** prints first line fine, then returns the out of range error

File: Is a simple text file with 20 lines, no more than 50 chars per line

FYI - Removed range line and printed both type(list) and length(20). Printed specific indexes without issue (unless >1 in a row)

Able to get the desired result with different code, but trying to improve using with/as

Comment: try with: with open('file') as f: 
      for line in f.readlines():

Comment: @eyllanesc Or just `for line in f`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually iterate over a file. Which is what you should be doing here.

```
with open('file') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
        # Get out of the loop if we hit 10 lines
        if i >= 10:
            break
        # Line already has a '\n' at the end
        print(line, end='')
```

The reason that your code is failing is because of your list comprehension:

```
[line.strip('\n') for line in f]
```

The first time through your loop that consumes *all* of the lines in your file. Now your file has no more lines, so the next time through it creates a list of all the lines in your file and tries to get the `[1]`st element. But that doesn't exist because there are no lines at the end of your file.

If you wanted to keep your code mostly as-is you could do

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
for i in range(10):
    print(lines[i])
```

But that's also silly, because you could just do

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

But that's *also* silly if you just want up to the 10th line, because you could do this:

```
with open('file') as f:
    print('\n'.join(f.readlines()[:10]))
```

---

Some further explanation:

The shortest **and worst** way you could fix your code is by adding one line of code:

```
with open('file') as f: 
      for i in range(0,10):
          f.seek(0)  # Add this line
          print([line.strip('\n') for line in f][i])
```

Now your code will work - but this is a *horrible* way to get your code to work. The *reason* that your code isn't working the way you expect in the first place is that files are consumable iterators. That means that when you read from them eventually you run out of things to read. Here's a simple example:

```
import io

file = io.StringIO('''
This is is a file
It has some lines
okay, only three.
'''.strip())

for line in file:
    print(file.tell(), repr(line))
```

This outputs

```
18 'This is is a file\n'
36 'It has some lines\n'
53 'okay, only three.'
```

Now if you try to read from the file:

```
print(file.read())
```

You'll see that it doesn't output anything. That's because you've "consumed" the file. I mean obviously it's still on disk, but the iterator has reached the end of the file. But as shown, you can seek in the file.

```
print(file.tell())
file.seek(0)
print(file.tell())
print(file.read())
```

And you'll see your entire file printed. But what about those other positions?

```
file.seek(36)
print(file.read())  # => okay, only three.
```

As a side note, you can also specify how much to read:

```
file.seek(36)
print(file.read(4))  # => okay
print(file.tell())  # => 40
```

So when we read from a file or iterate over it we consume the iterator and get to the end of the file. Let's put your new tools to work and go back to your original code and explore what's happening.

```
with open('file') as f:
    print(f.tell())
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    print(f.tell())
    print(len([line for line in f]))
    print(lines)
```

You'll see that you're at a different location in the file. And the second list comprehension produces an empty list. That's because when a list comprehension is evaluated it executes immediately. So when you do this:

```
for i in range(10):
    print([line.strip('\n') for line in f][i])
```

What you're doing the first time, `i = 0` and then the list comprehension reads to the end of the file. Now it takes the `[0]`th element of the list, or the first line in the file. But your file iterator is at the end of the file.

So now we get back to the beginning of the list and `i = 1`. Now we iterate to the end of the file, but we're already at the end so there are no lines to read, and we've got an empty list `[]` that we try to get the `[0]`th element of. But there's nothing there. So we get an `IndexError`.

List comprehensions *can* be useful, but when you're beginning it's usually much easier to write a for loop and then turn it into a list comprehension. So you might write something like this:

```
with open('file') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(file, start=10):
        if i < 10:
            print(line.rstrip())
```

Now, we shouldn't print inside a list comprehension, so instead we'll collect everything. We start out by putting what we want:

```
[line.rstrip()
```

Now add the for bit:

```
[line.rstrip() for i, line in enumerate(f)
```

And finally add the filter and our closing brace:

```
[line.rstrip() for i, line in enumerate(f) if i < 10]
```

For more on list comprehensions, this is a fantastic resource: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Comment: Thank you, Wayne.  Using code in front of my 'for' is still something i'm trying to wrap my head around.

Comment: If this solves your problem, you can (and should) mark it accepted via the check mark off to the left there `<------`. If it's especially helpful, you can upvote it as well. When you say "Using code in front of my `for`", do you mean a list comprehension (e.g. `[thing for thing in data]`), or do you mean nesting the `for` inside another block, like `with open(...) as f: for line in f: print(line)`?

Comment: ***Ah ok, so when i used 'line.strip' in front of my 'for' statement it actually applies 'line.strip' to every line in the file and outputs the result into a list of the lines. And when i iterated over it again, it knows (somehow) that its already dealt with all of the lines in the file, so it doesn't have anything to work with and just outputs an empty list - hence the error. Thanks for taking the time to explain this. :)

Comment: Done and done :)  Yes, I meant the list comprehension part.

Comment: Yes - your reasoning is correct. I'm adding more to my answer to more clearly explain your existing code :)

Comment: Whoops, got a little caught up - it's in there now!